# I am looking for dim mutiple variables in the for loop

Tags: vba, excel

Can I do this?

```
For i = 1 To 127
    Dim cell&i as Range
Next
```

Because I have a lot of cells need to dim.

Comment: It's not possible without using a hack. what are you actually trying to do? It's strange to dim 127 variables of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

Try using an array instead:

```
Dim nCells As Long
Dim myCells() As Range 'store them in an array

nCells = 127
ReDim myCells(1 To nCells)
For i = 1 To nCells
    Set myCells(i) = Range("A1").Offset(i,i) ' or whatever...
Next i
```

Maybe you should show us what you are trying to achieve exactly. This pattern looks a bit unusual.